# How to look on a Subfolder using FOR loop in windows CLI

Tags: command-line

Hey Team I am trying to execute an app that is in a folder constantly changing the name due to version difference `C:\root\my Folder\subfolder_Ver_1\app.exe`

I want to look in my Folder and find app.exe not specifying the `Subfolder_Ver_1`

This is the code I have:

```
FOR /r %F IN (*.*) DO start app "%F"
```

Any idea??

Comment: Maybe forfiles will work better for this. For example, this will find test.txt and returns its full path: `forfiles /s /m test.txt /c "cmd /c echo @path`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe forfiles is better suited for this job.

Here's an example script of how you would create a .cmd file that does this.

```
::  -- Navigate to the base folder.
    cd /d "c:\root\My folder"

::  -- Search for the app and launch it.
    forfiles /s /m app.exe /c "cmd /c @path"
```

Do note, if there are more apps with the same name, this will launch them all.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your root folder

If you want to keep using the IF statement, I found this works as well

```
@echo on
for /r %%F in (app.exe) do %%F
```

name your cmd file and then run it. if there is only one subfolder called SubFolder_Ver_?, then you are good. but if there are many Subfolders, then this will run them all. If that is the case then use the IF statement to extract the latest folder. if you give me more info, then I can fix that too.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
for /r /d %G in (*)do pushd "%~dpnxG" && start "" /b app "%~dpnxG" && popd
```

Or...

```bash
for /r /d %G in (*)do start "" /b /d "%~dpnxG" app
```

Or...

```bash
for /r /d %G in (*)do start "" /w /d "%~dpnxG" app
```

Or...

```bash
for /f delims^= %G in ('where /r . "App.exe"') do start "" /w "%~G"
```

Or...

```bash
for /f delims^= %G in ('where /r . "App.exe"') do start "" /b "%~G"
```